# Условие для X-Frame-Options

Tags: header, php, iframe, условия

На сайте прописал код, который запрещает открытие сайта через фреймы:

```
header("X-Frame-Options: Deny");
```

Теперь когда открывают сайт через iframe, там ничего не показывает, белый фон. Мне нужно прописать там текст, например, если сайт открыли через фрейм, то: "**Запрещено**"

- Как тут дать условие?

Благодарю за внимание!

Comment: @Maqsood, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать на JavaScript.

Создается защитный слой с высотой и шириной 100%, перекрывающий всю страницу, в котором можете прописать все, что угодно. Этот слой будет отображаться при загрузке страницы:

```
<div id="framebuster" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed;">
    <a href="http://your_site" target="_top">Перейти на сайт</a>
</div>
```

После этого слоя в коде прописывается JavaScript, проверяющий, не загружена ли страница во фрейме:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Если страница не во фрейме,
if (top.document.domain==document.domain) {
    // скрываем защитный слой
    document.getElementById('framebuster').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

В результате вместо вашей страницы во фрейме отобразится защитный слой с ссылкой на ваш сайт.

Важно знать, что этот метод легко обходится добавлением атрибута sandbox в iframe.